# How to make quarto callouts appear in TOC

Tags: quarto, callouts

I'm working on a quarto webpage and want the callout block to appear in the TOC in the output document as shown up in the image below. Can someone help me get this done, I went through the documentation but couldnt find anything. I realize this is not a regular behaviour for callouts but would appreciate any workaround to make them appear in the TOC for my usecase.

My code:

```
---
title: "some title"
format: html
---


## 1.1.0 Review

::: {.callout-caution appearance="simple" icon=false}
### Exercise 1.1.1

some code


some text
:::
```

Expected output:

[image: expected output]